# How can I test conditional rendering on a react component with react testing lib?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, testing, ecmascript-6

So this is the component I am attempting to test:

```
export const Profile: FC<Props> = props => {
  const { navigation, profileDetails, fetchProfileDetails } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    !profileDetails && fetchProfileDetails();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {get(profileDetails, 'error') ? (
        <Error message={get(profileDetails, 'message') || 'Unknown Error'} />
      ) : (
        <UserContainer navigation={navigation} userDetails={profileDetails} />
      )}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

As you may see there are a couple of components, `Error` and `UserContainer` components.

This is my test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { dummyUserInfo } from '../../shared/models/UserInfo.model';
import { Profile } from './Profile';
import { shallowRender } from '../../shared/services/testHelper';

const mockNavigation: any = { getParam: () => undefined };

const mockError: any = { profileDetails: { error: 'test error' } };

describe('Profile Scene', () => {
  it('renders error', () => {
    const tree = shallowRender(<Profile profileDetails={mockError} navigation={mockNavigation} />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And this is how the snapshot for the `renders error` test looks:

```
exports[`Profile Scene renders error 1`] = `
<ScrollViewMock>
  <UserContainer
    navigation={
      Object {
        "getParam": [Function],
      }
    }
    userDetails={
      Object {
        "profileDetails": Object {
          "error": "test error",
        },
      }
    }
  />
</ScrollViewMock>
`;
```

So is that a proper way to test that kind of things or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You should test for both scenarios separately.
One for the error container and one for User Container.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Profile } from './Profile';
import { shallowRender } from '../../shared/services/testHelper';

const mockNavigation: any = { getParam: () => undefined };

describe('Profile Scene', () => {
  it('renders error', () => {
    const mockError: any = { profileDetails: { error: 'test error', message: 'test error' } };
    const tree = shallowRender(<Profile profileDetails={mockError} navigation={mockNavigation} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Error).exists()).to.equal(true);
    expect(wrapper.find(UserContainer).exists()).to.equal(false);
  });

  it('renders naviagtion', () => {
    const mockError: any = { profileDetails: { error: null, message: '' } };
    const tree = shallowRender(<Profile profileDetails={mockError} navigation={mockNavigation} />);
    expect(wrapper.find(Error).exists()).to.equal(false);
    expect(wrapper.find(UserContainer).exists()).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```